# EVP_DigestVerifyUpdate Alternative for OpenSSL

Tags: c++, openssl, cryptography

EVP_DigestVerifyUpdate function takes data and hash it.

Is there a function that takes the data, but don't hash it?

Comment: Hashing the data is the entire purpose of this function, so it's not clear what you mean.

Comment: I want to verify data that had been hashed. as c# function verifyHash that takes a hashed data and signature to verify it. @mnistic

Comment: Did you have a look at [`EVP_PKEY_verify`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/EVP_PKEY_verify.html)?

Comment: Yes, but when i determine a hash function using EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_signature_md , it doesn't work. it works only when i don't use this function @MarekKlein

Answer (score 0):

The `EVP_DigestVerify` sequence is:

```
EVP_DigestVerifyInit()
EVP_DigestVerifyUpdate()
EVP_DigestVerifyFinal()
```

Therefore, if you have computed your digest elsewhere, (the question is why would you do that?) you should be able to call `EVP_DigestVerifyFinal()` directly:

```
ctx->md_data = my_computed_digest;
ctx->digest->md_size = my_computed_digest_size;
ret = EVP_DigestVerifyFinal(ctx, sig, siglen);
```

Comment: thanks for replying, but when i execute it, Exception is triggered at EVP_DigestVerifyFinal (NULL Exception)

Comment: This won't work with more recent version of OpenSSL since EVP_MD_CTX is an opaque structure.